# Intellij cursor keeps following mouse and highlight

Tags: intellij-idea

For some reason Intellijs text cursor keeps following my mouse and highlighting everything. Is there some setting that can do that? I can't seem to find it from searching the settings. Where else could it be?

Answer (score 191):

If you have a touchscreen try touching it somewhere. It helped me to solve the issue.

Found the solution in [this thread on the JB website](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000577850-Intellij-IDE-caret-following-cursor).

Comment: Did the trick on my Dell XPS 9370 w/ Debian 9.5
tl;dr: "If you have a touchscreen, touch it and it will SOLVE this issue."

Comment: Solved the issue on Lenovo Thinkpad. Thanks a ton. I was using ideamvim and unnecessarily blaming the extension.

Comment: Wow, just wow. I was blaming ideavim for the past 2 hours as well until I see this. Solved the issue on Asus UX303 Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Dell 9560 fixed. This had been driving me nuts

Comment: Thank you - been bugging me for about 2 months now.
WebStorm wasn't even on that monitor (the touchscreen one).

Comment: Solved on Dell Inspiron!

Comment: Solved on Dell XPS 9550

Comment: Solved on Thinkpad T25 Ubuntu 18.04. What a relief!

Comment: Solved on Ubuntu 18.04 on a Dell Inspiron. Thanks!

Comment: If this is the correct solution then someone should close it so that we don't get comments from people saying "thanks/solved on distro version on laptop"

Comment: Please mark this as the correct answer of you will keep getting thank you messages,
here is mine -
works for me on Thinkpad T490, Centos 8

Answer (score 3):

I use a touch screen monitor and i deal with the same issue. my mouse cursor remained in selecting state and highlight every thing.
I touch somewhere on the my monitor screen once and solved this problem without closing app.

Other solutions are:
close and open app
/   restarting computer

Comment: Cool, worked for me as well

Answer (score 1):

I had that problem twice on two different computers in different jetbrains IDEs, gogland and pycharm.

The solution, as annoying as easy, restarting of the machine. Restarting the IDE or even up/downgrading did not help.

Comment: I had the same problem and I couldn't find any solutions to that because I though there was an option in Intellij. I never though I had to restart the computer to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

1. Go to setting
2. Search for mouse
3. In the editor action, edit the **Add rectangular selection on mouse drag**

[image: Here is a helping Screen Shot]

Answer (score 0):

Mohammad Reisi's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/72196705/22460400) worked for me. I had to open my laptop (I use 2 monitors with the laptop closed and touch the screen a few times and then closed the laptop and it worked.